# Current tick falling outside of position's lower and upper tick

Tags: ether, ethereumjs, uniswapv3, usdc

I would like some assistance on this matter: My pool of reference is ETH/USDC and if my current tick is below my position’s lower tick, am I right to state that all of my position ETH will be converted to USDC? If so, how do I calculate the new amount of USDC? Thanks